# Vue SPA frontend with Laravel Backend File placement and .htaccess settings for production

Tags: laravel, apache, vuejs3, single-page-application

So I had a lot of problems and couldn't find a solution for merging vue3 spa with laravel 10 api.
Finally got it working and wanted to save some time for all of you who have similar problem.

Solution:
Laravel project stays as it is with default apache2 configuration for laravel.

Compiled Vue files including index.html and assets folder are going into laravel's public dir.

All my api routes start with /api/.

App uses bearer for authentication.

And this is my .htaccess fle.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So that's all.